# R download.file() rename the downloaded file, if the filename already exists

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to download files off the internet using the download.file() command in a simple code (am complete newbie). The files are downloading properly. However, if a file already exists in the download destination, I'd wish to rename the downloaded file with an increment, as against an overwrite which seems to be the default process.

```
nse.url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2016/FEB/fo04FEB2016bhav.csv.zip"
nse.folder = "D:/R/Download files from Internet/"
nse.destfile = paste0(nse.folder,"fo04FEB2016bhav.csv.zip")
download.file(nse.url,nse.destfile,mode = "wb",method = "libcurl")
```

Problem w.r.t to this specific code: if "fo04FEB2016bhav.csv.zip" already exists, then get say "fo04FEB2016bhav.csv(2).zip"?

General answer to the problem (and not just the code mentioned above) would be appreciated as such a bottleneck could come up in any other situations too.

Comment: Maybe use `method=curl` and set the `-o` flag will force overwrite every time when calling `download.file`?

Comment: @ekstroem - apologies, I am new to R and unfortunately it sounds latin to me. I am so new to R that I don't understand the difference between libcurl/curl/etc. I tried reading up, but still not clear. Can you elaborate with an example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function below will automatically assign the filename based on the file being downloaded.  It will check the folder you are downloading to for the presence of a similarly named file.  If it finds a match, it will add an incrementation and download to the new filename.

ekstroem's suggestion to fiddle with the curl settings is probably a much better approach, but I wasn't clever enough to figure out how to make that work.

```
download_without_overwrite <- function(url, folder)
{
  filename <- basename(url)
  base <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)
  ext <- tools::file_ext(filename)

  file_exists <- grepl(base, list.files(folder), fixed = TRUE)

  if (any(file_exists))
  {
    filename <- paste0(base, " (", sum(file_exists), ")", ".", ext)
  }

  download.file(url, file.path(folder, filename), mode = "wb", method = "libcurl")
}

download_without_overwrite(
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nutterb/redcapAPI/master/README.md",
  folder = "[path_to_folder]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nse.url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2016/FEB/fo04FEB2016bhav.csv.zip"
nse.folder = "D:/R/Download files from Internet/"

#Get file name from url, with file extention
fname.x <- gsub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", nse.url)

#Get file name from url, without file extention
fname <- gsub("(.*)\\.csv.*", "\\1", fname.x)

#Get xtention of file from url
xt <- gsub(".*(\\.csv.*)", "\\1", fname.x)

#How many times does the the file exist in folder
exist.times <- sum(grepl(fname, list.files(path = nse.folder)))

if(exist.times){
   # if it does increment by 1
   fname.x <- paste0(fname, "(", exist.times + 1, ")", xt)
}

nse.destfile = paste0(nse.folder, fname.x)
download.file(nse.url, nse.destfile, mode = "wb",method = "libcurl")
```

### Issues

This approach will not work in cases where part of the file name already exists for example you have `url/test.csv.zip` and in the folder you have a file `testABC1234blahblah.csv.zip`. It will think the file already exists, so it will save it as `test(2).csv.zip`.

You will need to change the `#How many times does the the file exist in folder` part of the code accordingly.

Comment: dimitris_ps - thanks. Just to get around the problem of incrementing when the file names are approximately similar, would the grepl with "fixed=TRUE" solve it? My skillset in R is very basic, but I note that is the only real difference in your code vs what @Benjamin has in his response. (Hope that interests you)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the `fixed=TRUE` will not solve this. You would need to look into regular expressions to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer and shouldn't be considered as such, but the comment section above was too small to write it all.

I thought the `-O -n` options to curl could be used to but now that I looked at it more closely it turned out that it wasn't implemented yet. Now `wget` automatically increment the filename when downloading a file that already exists. However, setting `method="wget"` doesn't work with `download.file` because you are forced to set the destination file name, and once you do that you overwrite the automatic file increments.

I like the solution that @Benjamin provided. Alternatively, you can use

```
system(paste0("wget ", nse.url))
```

to get the file through the system (provided that you have `wget` installed) and let `wget` handle the increment.